# Yaesu memory programming - skip vs. select vs. off/blank? FTM-100/400 series

Tags: yaesu, radio-programming

I have a Yaesu FTM-400XDR, but this applies equally to at least the FTM-100 series and probably other radios.

When you program memory channels/frequencies, you can select one of three options:  Select, Skip and Off(blank).

Select is obvious - in memory scan mode, the radio scans these program settings and ignores all others.

Skip vs. Off/Blank is eluding me however.  What is the functional difference between them?  Is there some mode in the radio where they act differently?

Answer (score 3):

It seems on at least the FTM-400 series, there is a use for this.  You can set the scan mode to "all mem" or "select mem":

- in "all mem" mode, the radio will scan all of the programmed channels, *unless* they are set to "skip".  In other words, this gets "select" channels plus "off/blank" channels.
- in "select mem" mode, which seems to be the default, the radio will only scan "select" channels.  All others are skipped.

So in practice, this gives you three sets of programs:

- "Select" will always be scanned, in either mode; these are frequencies you always want to scan
- "Off/Blank" will only be scanned in "all mem" mode; these are frequencies you sometimes want to scan, but sometimes don't
- "Skip" will never be scanned; these are frequencies you never want to scan.

I just figured this out today and thought I'd share, in case it benefits others.